# Why I am getting NoClassDefFoundError: org.powermock/tests/utils/RunnerTestSuitChunker?

Tags: junit, powermock

I am writing JUnit Test case using powermock i.e. @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) and using @PrepareTest annotations and added all the Power mock dependencies but still why I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.powermock/tests/utils/RunnerTestSuitChunker.

Any Suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you added powermock jar in your java build path?

Comment: Do you have annotations on your test case class like this?@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TestClassName.class)

Comment: 1.Yes , I have added all the Power Mock jars in my pom.xml.

Comment: 2. Yes i have both 2 annotations on my class.

Comment: Why I am getting ClassNotFound for RunnerTestSuitChunker class and where is this class present?